# My 7265 Cub Cadet tractor will not start

Tags: starting, tractor

My 7265 series Cub Cadet tractor will not start.  First try it cranked the motor a couple seconds then the starter free wheeled.  The second time it free wheeled only.  The 3rd time and till now it does nothing.  No free wheeling or anything.

What is wrong? And how to I repair it?

Comment: Sounds like a bad starter to me.